# Qt Tree model and custom view based on Repeater

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

I'm working on a kind of audio workstation where the main data structure is a tree where the top-level nodes are 'Tracks', having 'Plugins' as children (which will in turn have 'Parameters' as children but I'm not there yet).

The model is built by subclassing QAbstractItemModel.

The view is QML and will be something like a tall Rectangle for each Track with a Column of smaller rectangles for each plugin, much like any mainstream DAW.

I thought I'd use nested Repeaters to build the view:

- QML Row:

  - Repeater (delegates are top-level nodes: tracks):

    - Repeater (delegates are children nodes: plugins)

The roadblock I can't seem to get past is related to how QML navigates the tree. (Well rather how little I understand how it works ;-)

In the code you see that the top-level Repeaters get the model as they should and the model has roles to access the relevant data.

It's the nested Repeaters that I can not get to work as intended. I can't access the data that I need from a nested repeater. I would have thought that nested repeaters interrogate the model by passing their delegate's index but it does not seem to be the case. The model's data() uses the internalPointer and this is always a pointer to a top level item (a track).

I tried several things:

- passing the track's childItems list: that creates the correct number of plugins but give no access to their data
- scrapping the whole tree model and reverting to list models where each items holds a sub-model with their children: not very elegant

I spent days reading Qt docs and can't figure out if my troubles come from my model implementation or from my understanding of Repeaters, or of QML in general.

main.py, including model and treeitem:

```
import os


from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Qt, QModelIndex, QAbstractItemModel


class TreeItem(QObject):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.parentItem = parent
        self.itemData = data
        self.childItems = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"TreeItem: name: {self.itemData[0]}"

    def appendChild(self, item):
        self.childItems.append(item)

    def child(self, row):
        return self.childItems[row]

    def childCount(self):
        return len(self.childItems)

    def columnCount(self):
        return len(self.itemData)

    def data(self, column):
        try:
            return self.itemData[column]
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def parent(self):
        return self.parentItem

    def row(self):
        if self.parentItem:
            return self.parentItem.childItems.index(self)

        return 0

    def plugs(self):
        return self.childItems


class TreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    TrackRole = Qt.UserRole + 1
    PluginRole = Qt.UserRole + 2
    ParameterRole = Qt.UserRole + 3

    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(TreeModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.rootItem = TreeItem('root')
        self.setupModelData(data, self.rootItem)

    def roleNames(self):
        roles = {
            self.TrackRole: b"track",
            self.PluginRole: b"plugins",
            self.ParameterRole: b"parameter"
        }
        return roles

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        if parent.isValid():
            return parent.internalPointer().columnCount()
        else:
            return self.rootItem.columnCount()

    def data(self, index, role):
        print(index)
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        item = index.internalPointer()
        if role == self.PluginRole:
            return item.plugs()
        elif role == self.TrackRole:
            return item.data(0)
        elif role == self.ParameterRole:
            return item.data(1)

        return item.data(0)
        # return item.data(index.column())

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return Qt.NoItemFlags

        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.rootItem.data(section)

        return None

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QModelIndex()

        if not parent.isValid():
            parentItem = self.rootItem
        else:
            parentItem = parent.internalPointer()

        childItem = parentItem.child(row)
        if childItem:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, childItem)
        else:
            return QModelIndex()

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QModelIndex()

        childItem = index.internalPointer()
        parentItem = childItem.parent()

        if parentItem == self.rootItem:
            return QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(parentItem.row(), 0, parentItem)

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        if parent.column() > 0:
            return 0

        if not parent.isValid():
            parentItem = self.rootItem
        else:
            parentItem = parent.internalPointer()

        return parentItem.childCount()

    def setupModelData(self, data, parent):
        root = parent

        for t in data:
            t_data = [t['name'], t['bus']]
            track = TreeItem(t_data, root)
            root.appendChild(track)
            for p in t['plugs']:
                p_data = [p['pname']]
                processor = TreeItem(p_data, track)
                track.appendChild(processor)
                for param in p['params']:
                    param_data = [param['name'], param['value']]
                    parameter = TreeItem(param_data, processor)
                    processor.appendChild(parameter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    d = [{'name': 'track1', 'bus': 2, 'plugs': [{'pname': 'gain', 'params': [{'name': 'gain', 'value': 0}]},
                                                {'pname': 'eq', 'params': [{'name': 'freq', 'value': 1},
                                                                           {'name': 'gain', 'value': 6}]}]},
         {'name': 'track2', 'bus': 4, 'plugs': [{'pname': 'panner', 'params': [{'name': 'speed', 'value': 10}]},
                                                {'pname': 'compressor', 'params': [{'name': 'ratio', 'value': 3},
                                                                                   {'name': 'threshold', 'value': 20}]}]},
         {'name': 'track3', 'bus': 1, 'plugs': [{'pname': 'phaser', 'params': [{'name': 'speed', 'value': 10}]},
                                                ]}
         ]

    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    model = TreeModel(d)

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('my_model', model)
    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.qml"))

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The QML view:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQml.Models 2.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: main_window
    width: 1024
    height: 600
    visible: true
    color: "#181818"
    title: qsTr("Tree Tests")

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Row {
            spacing: 5
            anchors.fill: parent
            Repeater {
                model: my_model
                Rectangle {
                    color: "red"
                    height: 600
                    width: 100
                    Label {
                        id: lbl
                        text: model.track
                    }
                    Column {
                        spacing: 5
                        anchors.top: lbl.bottom
                        Repeater {
                            model: plugins //unsure of what to pass here...
                            Rectangle {
                                color: "blue"
                                width: 80
                                height: 50
                                Label {
                                    text: plugins[0][0] //should be a plugin name here
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: *"It's the nested Repeaters that I can not get to work as intended."* -- What does that mean? I don't think you've described what problem you're having. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: @JarMan Sorry I see now that I was not clear at all. Please see the updated post. TLDR is that I can't access a sub-node's data from a nested repeater.

Comment: [comment unrelated to the actual question] Are you **really** sure you want to use a Qt model to do that? I don't see any benefit in doing that, especially for audio-oriented applications (which in Python have a very high performance priority, since it's not time safe): I'd suggest to create your own data model based on simpler concepts, and eventually create an abstraction layer whenever you actually need to display the object structure in an item view.

Comment: @musicamante You're absolutely right, but this project is really a remote controller for an external device. It won't have anything to do with the audio thread whatsoever. Plus it serves as a cool study project for Qt Quick and the general Model/VIew pattern, which I expect to play a bigger role in my programming.